# How to get accented characters working in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Been search for about 2 days now and cant quite understand how to make accented characters work in HTML templates. For example, I was working on building a simple dtatable with Angular Material that looks like this :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Priorité">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Priorité </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Priorité}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Description}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="Other">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Other</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Other}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

I get the following error when using the template above because I used "é":

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Lexer Error: Unexpected character [é] at column 16 in expression [element.Priorité]' at column 17 in [ {{element.Priorité}} ] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@134:44 ("derCellDef mat-sort-header> Priorité </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">[ERROR ->] {{element.Priorité}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

To work around the issue I just remove the accented characters. I rather avoid this if possible. Is French characters not supported in Angular 2,4,5?

Comment: It's not an angular limitation, but a JavaScript one. You can't use dot notation if your attribute name contains special chars. You can use brackets though: `{{element['Priorité']}}`

Comment: Sure did the trick thank you so much for that. Working perfectly now.

Comment: it's better change the "property" Priorité to Priorite. I'm not sure what will be happen when typescript it was transpile to javascript